# NestJS Microservices (MQTT Transporter) reveive hex data as Buffer

Tags: javascript, nestjs

NestJS uses MQTT.js under the hood for MQTT based communication (as far as I have seen). I am trying to receive hex data as Buffer, but received data always gets decoded to text. I can't encode it correctly to get the sent hex data. I tried a ton of encoding schemes.

Is there a way to tell NestJS that data should not be decoded to text?

Example:

One client publishes 0xfa. Another client (NestJS application) listens to this topic and receives a string with in this case a non-printable character. When I am trying to convert it back to a Buffer with `Buffer.from(message, 'utf-8')`, I get 0xefbfbd. Converting it back with e.g. `Buffer.from(message, 'ascii')` results in 0xfd.

This problem occurs with hex data ranging from 0x80 to 0xff, as it is not standardized I guess (ascii e.g. is standardized from 0x00 to 0x7f). Therefore when I am trying to send 0x01 I have no problem receiving a character and converting it back to 0x01 with `Buffer.from(message, 'utf-8')` and `Buffer.from(message, 'ascii')`.

Comment: do you mind adding some example to replicate this? because, if I read the question as it is, you should be able to convert it as text with something like this `Buffer.from('68656c6c6f', 'hex').toString('utf-8')`. which should returned a string `hello`.

Comment: Of course, I edited the post above to make it more clear for everybody. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmmm, I don't know on what format the client pushes the data. But, assuming it is in hexadecimal, then I guess you need to check with the client. because you're right, it should be from 00 to 7f. Looking at this, I feel like it should be converted from hex to ascii (instead directly into ascii)

Comment: I could solve this. The context argument, that the function receives, which processes the event, contains the buffer. Many thanks anyways!

Comment: See https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt#context

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue can be nailed down to Buffer in NodeJS? See these examples executed in Node REPL:

`Buffer.from(Buffer.from([0,1,128]).toString(), 'ascii')` //<Buffer 00 01 fd>

`Buffer.from(Buffer.from([0,1,128]).toString(), 'utf-8')` //<Buffer 00 01 ef bf bd>

Here once can clearly see, that 128 decimal (which is 0x80) got somehow "lost" / converted back in the wrong way.

Comment: Even better example:

`Buffer.from(Buffer.from([0x0,0x1,0x80]).toString(), 'ascii')` //<Buffer 00 01 fd>

Comment: `Buffer.from(Buffer.from([0x0,0x1,0x80]).toString('ascii'), 'ascii')` //<Buffer 00 01 00>

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The context argument, that the function receives, which processes the event, contains the buffer. See https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt#context